# How to pause a watir cucumber script mid-execution and then resume it?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, watir, linux-mint

P.S.: No, I do not want to debug my script. It is pretty awesome.

The problem is the application under test. If I place a few orders, it crashes. So what I want to do is: mid-execution, when I see that the application is crashed, I want to pause the test script, bring the application back up and running, and then resume the test.

I know that this is not the point of time when I should be running the test scripts as the application is not stable enough, but the developers are working on it and hopefully soon enough, they will fix it. I am just curious to know if there is a solution, because I couldn't find one. Of course I could've integrated bringing the application up again when it crashes in my tests, but that is not what I want to do.

My system:

OS: Linux Mint

Tests: Watir (Ruby) + Cucumber on Chrome

I run the tests on linux terminal using cucumber tags.

I just want to know in general if there is any way to pause and resume execution. For example, when I want to stop all the tests, I give the command line interruption Ctrl + C. So is there any such interrupt command to pause and resume?

Comment: How do you "see" that the application has crashed? Is there an element that appears on the web page that you could use as a "crash identifier"?

Comment: And a follow-up question: Does the crash happen at random places in the process of ordering, or always after the same action?

Comment: Does your app have session ids and authentication? If yes, then your existing test session will not continue after restarting the app mid-test. As you mentioned, app restart will have to be integrated into the test with re-authentication for seamless execution.

In case there is no session issue, you can identify that the application has crashed using whatever identifies the crash (text/ element/ etc), pause the test for certain amount of time and in meantime restart the app.

Comment: @AbeHeward Answer to your Q1: I can see the application has crashed. Take the example of a shopping website. I know something is wrong when I am placing orders and then suddenly all the products have no prices anymore. Answer to your Q2: The crash does not always happen after the same action. Again the example of the shopping website. I keep placing orders because say I want to check that the inventory is handled properly after every type of order: orders containing multiple products, multiple quantities, etc. The prices go away sometimes after 10 orders and sometimes after 20. Its sporadic.

Comment: Are you using a Page Object design pattern with your code base?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML examples of the page with and without the product prices so that I can use it for my pseudo-code answer? It's hard to know if I can be helpful without some example page code to work with.

Comment: @AbeHeward, I'm not looking for a solution to my specific code, I just want to know in general if there is any way to pause and resume execution. For example, when I want to stop all the tests, I give the command line interruption Ctrl + C. So is there any such interrupt command to pause and resume. I will include this bit in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since you want a "general" answer, here goes...

Based on your context, you are looking for a "crashed" condition in your project.

My own approach to solving this problem would involve writing a helper method that would look for this condition and, if true, it would "pause". For example...

`def pause_if_crashed
  sleep 30 if @browser.product_price.nil?
end`

Then I would sprinkle this helper method in likely "crash" spots in my other functional methods.

Without more specifics about your needs, this is about as helpful as I can get, I think.

Comment: Thanks @AbeHeward for your reply, I think I can make this work.